# AngularJS HTTP Post to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, post

I am posting some data to a `php` page from `angularjs` controller using the `$http` method as shown below.

```
$scope.login = function(){
    var data = {
        'username' : $scope.username,
        'password' : $scope.password
    };
    $http.post('login.php', data).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

I know I can retrieve this data in `php` using :

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

But I was wondering if there is better way in `angularjs` so I could use the simple `$_POST` in `php` to retrieve the data.

In `jQuery` we could just simply use `$.post` and those are available for `php` in `$_POST`. Why for `angularjs` that is not that simple.
Is there any way to populate `$_POST` of `php` when we do a `$http` `post` request in `angularjs`. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receive json post with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: is this in service??

Comment: I checked the post you mentioned. But that post doesn't explain how to populate `$_POST`

Comment: @abdulla this is a simple controller file

Comment: You'll need to override `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest` to a transformer that serialises the `data` into a standard URL-encoded format instead of JSON. Read the documentation for some samples. That's just to point you in the right direction, if someone wants to develop this into a full answer by all means please do.

Comment: `if($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']==='application/json') $_POST=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your request to `php known` format.
I use `jQuery` `$.param` method to build it. You can write your own.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($http) {  
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $http.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
            return $.param(data);
        };
    }]);
```

---

`urlencoded` is followed simple format:

```
username=Name&password=My%20Password
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g22th4Lt/)

Comment: getting an empty array when `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I add fiddle for this

Comment: Be carefull with `Content-Type` capitalization. One already exists, and if you write it wrong - two headers will be sended. HTTP server selects one of this (undefined behavior)

Comment: @Adersh, success? Or still have issues?

Comment: I can't understand how the data is to be received in php for this method. via `$_POST` I am getting an empty array.

Comment: Are you check header name capitalization? It should be exactly `Content-Type`, not `Content-type`. Also, you can see, how it works in the fiddle(Just change httpbin.org to your server).

Answer (score 2):

Got it working using `jQuery` `$.param` method. Thanks to vp_arth's answer. I just added this answer as it might help someone. This can be used if it is needed for only one request.

```
$scope.login = function(){
    var data = {
        'username' : $scope.username,
        'password' : $scope.password
    };

    $http({
        url: "login.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param(data)
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

};
```

Comment: It usable if you have only one request. I strongly recommend to use `transformRequest`, if you have more than one post request in your project. It left your code clean and readable, like `$http.post(url, data)`

Comment: yes,..you are correct. I have accepted and voted up your answer :) just added this answer as it might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

well I just use this in my controller class, so all my post requests: normal ones with jQuery or the ones through angular **all end up being in `$_post`**

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty( $_POST ))
        $_POST=$_REQUEST = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), true );
```

have fun,

Comment: More correct to check `Content-type` header as I wrote in comment above.   To be sure, that client sends json.

Comment: @vp_arth, not necessarily, if `$_post` is empty so it's from angular, no need for more complexity here.

Comment: It looks more complex for me now. `empty($_POST)` is incorrect and magic. It can be empty in other cases. Also what should we doing with other queries, like `PUT` or  `PATCH`?

Comment: @vp_arth OP asked about POST, for other cases you could use a `switch` statement. `$_post` is an array so we can always check it with the `empty` function, why incorrect??